# Repeating logcat warning about Handler and UI thread

Tags: android, android-service, android-handler

I have a Service and a Timer which sends messages to a Handler which sends broadcast intent to my activities. So, every time my logcat fills full by this message:

`W/HandlerScheduledExecuto(11200): Task does not implement UiTask. Consider using NamedUiRunnable for eky@6512b2c0`

This log warning appears even if app is closed (Service keep working). Also logcat doesn't indicate my app as a source of this warming. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Is your `Handler` declared on UI thread or worker thread? Also, you can send a Broadcast from any thread, so you shouldn't need a handler for that anyway. Where does the `Context` come from that is used in the `Handler` to `sendBroadcast`?

Comment: @Jakar Context for `sendBroadcast(intent)` taken from the Service

Comment: @Jakar It means I call `sendBroadcast(intent)` directly from the Service

Comment: You are getting that message because you are, likely, using the incorrect (maybe even a static) context.

Comment: I'd recommend getting rid of the Handler, and just calling `sendBroadcast` directly from `run()` of your `TimerTask`. Don't use a `final` or `static` context. Use `getBaseContext()` inside the `run()` method. If that doesn't solve it, then you should post some code. Oh, and don't use `getApplicationContext()`.

Comment: @Jakar Thank you. I put `getBaseContext().sendBroadcast` directly in `run()` and this works fine. But I still have this warning. And now I realy don't know where should I find it..

Comment: Then you should try doing some debugging. If logs don't help you, then isolate the code you're debugging as much as you can, and remove pieces of it until you find which piece is causing the error. It may be an issue in the `BroadcastReceiver`. I probably can't help any more than that, though. I've kinda just been guessing this whole time.

Comment: @Jakar ok, I'll try. Also, should I use `getBaseContext` in all my app code instead of `getApplicationContext`?

Comment: Only use [`getApplicationContext()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()) when you understand the implications of using it and you know you need it. I personally keep a private `Context` variable in every activity which I assign from the `Context` passed into `onCreate`. Using `getBaseContext()` would be fine. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext() regarding getApplicationContext. Mainly, don't use getApplicationContext to register `BroadcastReceiver`s

Comment: @Jakar Thanks to you I've made some refactoring of my code and it seems now better, warning appears much less)

Comment: Also, reason of log cat madness was Google Now widget on the desk